# Shapes displayed on a canvas in php?

Tags: php, canvas, geometry, shapes

Question is I need to display these shapes I have created by displaying them on a canvas(background) and move them/resize them.First of all where should I create the canvas? Should it have its own function? Another thing is I know I need this header: header ('Content-type: image/png'); to describe the display. Please help me so I can not only draw the shape and canvas but create two of each shape.

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>Shapes</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<?PHP
  class Shape {
  var $x;
  var $y;

  // constructor
  function Shape($nextx, $nexty) {
     $this->moveTo($nextx, $nexty);
  }

  // accessors for x & y coordinates
  function getX() {
     return $this->x;
  }
  function getY() {
     return $this->y;
  }
  function setX($thenewx) {
     $this->x = $newx;
  }
  function setY($thenewy) {
     $this->y = $newy;
  }

  // modify the shape coordinates
  function moveTo($thenewx, $thenewy) {
     $this->setX($thenewx);
     $this->setY($thenewy);
  }
  function rMoveTo($movedx, $movedy) {
     $this->moveTo(($this->getX() + $movedx), ($this->getY() + $movedy));
  }

  // abstract method to override
  function draw() {
  }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
  var $length;

  // constructor
  function Rectangle($length, $length, $initwidth, $initheight) {
     $this->Shape($nextx, $nexty);
     $this->setlength($initwidth);
  }

  // accessors for length
  function getlength() {
     return $this->length;
  }

  function setWidth($newlength) {
     $this->width = $newlength;
  }


  // draw the rectangle
  function draw() {
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  var $radius;

  // constructor
  function Circle($nextx, $nexty, $nextradius) {
     $this->Shape($nextx, $nexty);
     $this->setRadius($nextradius);
  }

  // accessors for radius attribute
  function getRadius() {
     return $this->radius;
  }
  function setRadius($newradius) {
     $this->radius = $newradius;
  }

  // draw the circle
  function draw() {

  }
}

?>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make images with PHP or use the HTML5 `canvas` tag? I'm asking because PHP does not have a canvas.

Comment: What @Halcyon said.   I would go a step further and remove your php class deffinitions from the html/php file.  Put in your php/html file(s) stuff like $square = new Rectangle(...);  $square->draw();  Your code looks nice, just organized a little funky :)